# Trying to split an equation, but it will not compile

Tags: split, latex

I am trying to split an equation because it is too long for the line. Here is the equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:eq37}
\begin{split}
Y(X) = P \left[ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(i \Omega b \left( X_c - X \right) \right)^{n}}{n!(n+b-1)!}+H(0.5-\textup{Re}(b) ) \frac{\sin{\theta_E}}{\sin{\left( \theta_E - \pi b \right)}} \\ 
\times \frac{b(-b)!}{(b+1)!} \Omega^{2} E^{1+b} \left(X_c - X \right)^{1-b} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( i \Omega b \left(X_c - X \right) \right)^{n}}{n!(n+1-b)!} \right],
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

The message I get back when compiling is:

> ```
> ! Extra }, or forgotten \right.
> <template> }
>             $\endtemplate 
> l.579 \end{split}
> ```

Comment: This is covered here: [`\left`/`\right` across multiline equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612/5764)

Answer (score 0):

\left and \right should be on the same line:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    \left( blah blah \right. \\
    \left. blah blah \right)
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

For your equation, try this:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:eq37}
\begin{split}
Y(X) = P \left[ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(i \Omega b \left( X_c - X \right) \right)^{n}}{n!(n+b-1)!}+H(0.5-\textup{Re}(b) ) \frac{\sin{\theta_E}}{\sin{\left( \theta_E - \pi b \right)}} \right. \\ 
\left. \times \frac{b(-b)!}{(b+1)!} \Omega^{2} E^{1+b} \left(X_c - X \right)^{1-b} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( i \Omega b \left(X_c - X \right) \right)^{n}}{n!(n+1-b)!} \right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```